# Formula Trouble in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a raw export of data, categorized by rows, amount, and date.

I'm having difficulty finding/combining various spreadsheet formula's to get the the total expenditure in say "Jan'20 for category XX"

I have currently tried a combination of Sumif/Index/Match formulas with no luck. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT#1:
Link to the google sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhXR1GYciIHiyioY8oVbnoEFtXAnpgVYvOGbBiqsXJk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Remember that we cannot see what you see. So while your post may make sense to you, it has no context, and therefore no meaning, to those of us "out here." Please, always share a link to your sheet or a copy of it, being sure to set permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." When you share the link, be clear about where formulas should go and what the desired result(s) should look like.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Thanks, apologies. I have just added the link to the google sheet, there should also be edit access enabled.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is in your shared sheet?  The formulas in B2, C2, and D2 seem to be doing what you want, aren't they?  If there is still an issue, please clarify what results you would like to see, and in which cells.  Or is the issue with the pivot table tab?    If the latter, is it because the months aren't coming out in the right order?  I have the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the correct numbers on your main page so the formulas which total for each month, and by each category, seem to be working properly.  I noticed that your pivot table wasn't sorting correctly.  this turned out to be because you had your date values in the Month column on the Export tab set as string values.  I converted these to date values, equal to the last day of the given month.  I did the same for the month headers on your Main tab.

Now the pivot table sorts by month correctly, since these are now numeric values.
See here for a sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmTgKqFZmKiP0k0iKDWGQlWVyKJF5PfglhcwhRj49Y4/edit?usp=sharing

If there is still an issue you need help with, please let us know, with the details.